# The conversion from String "@StartingDate" to type'Integer' is invalid

Tags: vb.net

I've googled that error(in title) but I can't seem to get it to help me. My goal is to insert all the data value into database table.
My query code;

```
Try
For Each value As Type.Structures.R_Warehouse In dataList
Dim sql As String = String.Empty
sql &= "DELETE FROM" & Common.Constant.TBL_R_WAREHOUSE & ""
sql &= "WHERE InvDate = HMCS.dbo.f_GetInvDate()"
sql &= "AND InvID = @InvID AND InvDate = HMCS.dbo.f_GetInvDate()"    

sql &= "INSERT INTO" & Common.Constant.TBL_H_WHSTRANS & ""
sql &= " SELECT (SELECT dbo.f_GetNewTransID(substring(convert(varchar,getdate(),112),3,6)) as ID)"
sql &= ",@InvID "
sql &= ",@ItemID "
sql &= ",@Qty "   
sql &= ",@StartingDate "
sql &= ",@SANote "
sql &= ",convert(varchar,GETDATE(),120)"
sql &= ",'" & Setting.SettingHelper.HostName & "'"

Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql.ToString, cn, tran)
With cmd
.Parameters.Add("@InvID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value.InvID
.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = value.ItemID
.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.Decimal, 4).Value = value.Qty
    
If IsDBNull("@StartingDate") = False Then
.Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.Date, 8).Value = value.StartingDate
End If
    
.Parameters.Add("@SANote", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = value.SANote
.ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

But it always gives me an error info

> The conversion from String "@StartingDate" to type'Integer' is invalid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've changed the code but you still haven't explained what you're actually trying to achieve with this: `If IsDBNull("@StartingDate") = False Then`. You're calling `IsDBNull` and passing it a `String` so how could that ever be `True`? Explain what you're trying achieve.

Comment: I suspect that you should get rid of that `If` statement altogether but you haven't provided enough information to tell. What type is `value.StartingDate`? I would think that it is either `Date`, `Date?` or `Object`.

Comment: As for the actual question, it is a type mismatch.  I suspect from the error message that the issue is the field in your database isn't actually a date datatype.  Perhaps update your question with the types/values of value.StartingDate and ensure the DB schema matches

Comment: I just want to insert deleted data into another table, but I got an error info when I trying to insert @StartingDate. It seems like I should to convert it. StartingDate is a Date in my database SQL.

Comment: I have tried to use this code before 
.Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = value.StartingDate 
but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: No, it doesn't give you the same error. There may be a different error but the error you specify in the title of this question wouldn't even happen with the change to the code you posted. How about you answer the question I asked? I'm volunteering my time to try to help here but you won't do your part. I didn't ask about your database. Read the question properly and answer that question.

Comment: On another note, it looks to me like your SQL code would fail even with this because you have no space after "DELETE FROM" or "INSERT INTO". Maybe your constants include brackets and so the space isn't strictly necessary but it should still be there for readability.

Comment: @user18387401 I'm really sorry for bad understanding. I tried to get rid off **IF** statement using this code;
.Parameters("@StartingDate").Value = Convert.ToDateTime(value.StartingDate).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
and I tried to breakpoint on this code, it shows me value like this;
value.StartingDate | #12:00:00 AM#

Comment: On an unrelated note, the whole point of a `With` block is to avoid repeating the same expression over and over, yet you use `With cmd` and then repeat `.Parameters` over and over. Use `With cmd.Parameters` and then just use `.Add` inside the block.

Comment: I think that the problem resides in your INSERT-query. Somewhere it seems to expect to get an integer value, but it actually receives a string value. You could start fixing issues like this by *always* including the target column names in your insert queries. If the issue persists, it will be a lot easier to resolve, since you will only need to compare the source column types (in the VALUES clause or the SELECT clause) with the corresponding target column types.

Comment: @BartHofland : I dont know how, but I tried to use this code 
**'.Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", Convert.ToDateTime(value.StartingDate))**
And I got the error message **SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between from 1/1/17531 12:00:00 AM to 12/31/9999 21:59:59 PM**

Comment: Do you use the `datetime` datatype in your database? The `datetime` datatype in SQL Server is different from the `Date` type in VB.NET. The first starts at 1/1/1753 and the latter starts at 1/1/1. What is the actual data type of your `value.StartingDate` attribute? Make sure that the starting date is indeed optional (not only in the database, but in your entire application logic). Note that `Convert.ToDateTime` would convert an empty `Date?` value to a `Date.MinValue` value, which you probably do *not* want to happen. Instead, you could use `If(value.StartingDate, DbNull.Value)`

Comment: Yes, I use datetime datatype for value.StartingDate

Comment: Also note that `SqlDbType.Date` does not represent SQL Server's `datetime` data type nor VB.NET's `Date` datatype (or the underlying `System.DateTime` datatype of the .NET Framework in general). It represents SQL Server's `date` datatype, which does not have a direct equivalent in VB.NET. By using `SqlDbType.Date`, the query will use an SQL variable with type `date`, effectively stripping off the time component of the value.

Comment: @BartHofland What is the code should I put in my parameter for representing StartingDate ? I don't have idea

Comment: You could try `.Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = If(value.StartingDate, CObj(DBNull.Value))` instead of the if-block. If it works depends on the fact if your database column is nullable and if you use a nullable data type in your VB.NET code (like `Date?`) for the `value.StartingDate` attribute.

Comment: @BartHofland : I got an error message like; **The first operand of a binary'If'expression must be nullable or reference type.** before I run the program.

Answer (score 0):

Even though my question in the comments wasn't answered, I think I can glean enough information from what was posted to work out what's going on and what should be done. It seems that we're just not going to get a clear explanation so a best guess is all I can provide.

It appears that the point of the `If` statement that is causing the problem is to insert `NULL` into the database if `value.StartingDate` is not set and insert the value that is set otherwise. As it stands, it appears that `value.StartingDate` is type `Date`. Note that `Date` and `DateTime` are the same type, just as `Integer` and `Int32` are the same type. In that case, it will ALWAYS have a value. Just as an `Integer` variable will be zero by default, so a `Date` variable will be #1/01/0001 00:00:00# by default. If you insist on using a `Date` property there then you need to look for that default value and use `DBNull.Value` if you find it. That could be done with an `If` block:

```vb
If value.StartingDate = Nothing Then
    .Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value
Else
    .Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = value.StartingDate
End If
```

It would be better to use the `If` operator though:

```vb
.Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = If(value.StartingDate = Nothing,
                                                            CObj(DBNull.Value),
                                                            value.StartingDate)
```

Note that I have used `Nothing` for comparison there because `Nothing` is always the default for value type variables. What that actually corresponds to depends on the type. For numeric types, it corresponds to zero, while it corresponds to `Date.MinValue` for the `Date` type.

That will work, but it's not the best solution.

A better solution would be to declare the property type `Date?`, i.e. `Nullable(Of Date)` rather than `Date`. If you want a variable to be able to contain no value then you should use a nullable type. That way, instead of the property containing `Date.MinValue` by default, it will genuinely contain `Nothing`, i.e. no value. It will only contain an actual `Date` value if you assign one. You can then do this:

```vb
.Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = If(value.StartingDate.HasValue,
                                                            value.StartingDate.Value,
                                                            CObj(DBNull.Value))
```

Note that `CObj` is used because the `If` operator requires both potential return values to be the same type or one type inherit the other. In this case, neither `DBNull` nor `Date` inherit the other, so at least one must be cast as `Object`. Everything inherits `Object`, so any other return value will be valid. This means that the return type of `If` is `Object`, but that's fine because it is being assigned the `Value` property of a parameter, which is also of type `Object`.

Comment: "As it stands, it appears that `value.StartingDate` is type `Date`." This is not true. It can also be of type `Date?` (which is equivalent to `Nullable(Of Date)`). At least that would be the data type that I would be using here, assuming that the corresponding column in the database is actually nullable.

Comment: @BartHofland, yes it is true, if you read all the information provided by the OP. I asked them explicitly what type that property/field was and they refused to answer multiple times, but they did say that it had the value `#12:00:00 AM#`. That looks like a `Date` with its default value, doesn't it? Why would a `Date?` have that value? It would have had to be explicitly set to that value which, while possible, is unlikely. You are right that `Date?` is the type that should be used, which is exactly why I stated in my answer that that was not the best solution and there was more to follow.

Comment: @user18387401 : I tried to use your code, but it could not be executed, cause an information appears like this;
"Unable to infer the common type of the second and third operands of the 'IF' Operator. A higher conversion from one type to the other is required".

Comment: @NurmanAde, I have addressed that in my edit by using `CObj`. I have also provided an explanation of why it's required. That's what I get for typing code directly here instead of into VS first and letting the compiler check my work.

Comment: @user18387401 : I tried to use this code; 

**.Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", Convert.ToDateTime(value.StartingDate)) **

But it shows me an error info like this; 
**SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between from 1/1/17531 12:00:00 AM to 12/31/9999 21:59:59 PM**

Comment: @NurmanAde, at no point did I suggest that you should use code like that. Do what I told you to do and it will work. If you don't do what I told you then I am not responsible for the results and will not be providing any further help.

Comment: @user18387401 . . . Actually... when a variable of type `Date?` has a concrete datetime value, it would be shown like that as well. You would not notice the difference by looking at that value. But in both cases (`Date` and `Date?`) the value would also include the date itself, not only the time. So the OP seems to be insecure in this regard as well.

Comment: @user18387401 : I have tried to use your code, and it shows me an error like this;
**The specified argument is not in the range of valid values. Parameter name : StringDate: Invalid SqlDbType enumeration value:31**

Comment: Thanks All... finally it was solved with: 
**.Parameters.Add("@StartingDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = If(value.StartingDate.Trim = "", CObj(DBNull.Value), CDate(value.StartingDate))**.
And I changed the structure from **Public StartingDate As DateTime = Nothing** to **Public StartingDate As String= "" ** where the variable of @StartingDate is saved in the device memory in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things in the code in the question that I would do differently - please don't take my code as being the paragon of VB.NET, but I think it is something closer to what you intend to do.

I had to guess at what you were trying to do with the SQL transaction.

Adding a `New SqlParameter With {...}` might seem tedious, but look at how easy it is to know what each parameter is for. Easy-to-read code pays for itself in ease of getting it right and maintenance.

If you are using a version of Visual Studio that doesn't allow multi-line strings then you really need to update it. To one that also uses [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings) ;)

Try to put spaces after commas to make the code easier to read.

My attempt at getting the code in the question to be what you need is:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes

' This is only for the example on SO.
Namespace Type.Structures
    Class R_Warehouse
        Property InvID As String
        Property ItemID As Integer
        Property Qty As Decimal
        Property StartingDate As Date?
        Property SANote As String
    End Class
End Namespace

Module Module1

    ' This is only for the example on SO.
    Friend Class Common
        Friend Class Constant
            Friend Shared TBL_R_WAREHOUSE As String
            Friend Shared TBL_H_WHSTRANS As String
        End Class
    End Class

    ' This is only for the example on SO.
    Friend Class Setting
        Friend Class SettingHelper
            Friend Shared Property HostName As String
        End Class
    End Class

    Sub X() ' I had no better name for this method.
        Dim dataList As New List(Of Type.Structures.R_Warehouse) ' Only for this SO code.
        Dim connStr = "your connection string goes here" ' Only for this SO code.

        Dim sqlDelete = $"DELETE FROM [{Common.Constant.TBL_R_WAREHOUSE}] WHERE InvDate = HMCS.dbo.f_GetInvDate() AND InvID = @InvID"

        'TODO: Put the column names in as indicated.
        Dim sqlInsert = $"INSERT INTO [{Common.Constant.TBL_H_WHSTRANS}]
                                 VALUES(put the column names here)
                                 SELECT (SELECT dbo.f_GetNewTransID(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112), 3, 6)) As ID)
                                               ,@InvID
                                               ,@ItemID
                                               ,@Qty
                                               ,@StartingDate
                                               ,@SANote
                                               ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120)
                                               ,@HostName"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            conn.Open()

            'TODO: Consider the scope of the transaction - maybe a transaction is needed individually for each item in dataList instead of all of them in one go.
            Dim tran = conn.BeginTransaction("OverallTransaction")

            Try

                For Each rwItem As Type.Structures.R_Warehouse In dataList

                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlDelete, conn, tran)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@InvId", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = rwItem.InvID})
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    End Using

                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlInsert, conn, tran)
                        'TODO: Set the .Size parameter for the VarChar to match the column in the database.
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@InvID", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = rwItem.InvID})
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@ItemID", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = rwItem.ItemID})
                        'TODO: Set the .Precision and .Scale values to match the column in the database.
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Qty", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal, .Precision = 8, .Scale = 4, .Value = rwItem.Qty})

                        Dim startDateParam = New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@StartingDate", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date}

                        ' The MinValue and MaxValue checks may or may not be needed.
                        If rwItem.StartingDate.HasValue AndAlso
                            rwItem.StartingDate > SqlDateTime.MinValue AndAlso
                            rwItem.StartingDate < SqlDateTime.MaxValue Then
                            startDateParam.Value = rwItem.StartingDate
                        Else
                            startDateParam.Value = DBNull.Value
                        End If

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(startDateParam)

                        'TODO: Set the .Size parameter for the VarChar to match the column in the database.
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@SANote", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = rwItem.SANote})

                        'TODO: Set the .Size parameter for the VarChar to match the column in the database.
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@HostName", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = Setting.SettingHelper.HostName})

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    End Using
                Next

                tran.Commit()

            Catch ex As Exception
                tran.Rollback()
                ' Do something useful
            End Try

        End Using

    End Sub

End Module
```